# Acer AOD260 No webcam after restoring?

Tags: webcam, acer-aspire

I have an Acer Aspire One D260 32-bit netbook.

I've restored the computer a few times & for awhile now, the webcam hasn't restored. I cannot find the webcam in "devices" & am unsure what to do to get it working again.

I'm obviously not tech savvy, so any advice would be amazing :)

Comment: What environment? Windows (which?), Linux (distribution, version?)? Everything up to date?

Answer (score 0):

first off by restore do you mean you have done a System restore from your recovery Partition OR Recovery Disk?

And you do not see the Webcam in the Device Manager? have you looked under the Imaging Device under device manager by clicking the + symbol?  Do you see any yellow questions marks in device manager? if you do then it means the webcam may not be installed.

Here is your Drivers List GO under the Camera Section and download and install one by one until your webcam works OR if you know which mntfr is your Webcam then just download that specific driver from the list:
 http://support.acer.com/us/en/product/default.aspx?tab=1&modelId=2438

Hope that Helps.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure the OP knows about Device Manager. Quite likely by "Devices" she means `Start / Devices and Printers`.